# Mount /tmp and /home to separate hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, mountpoint

is it possible to mount the root file system '/' on one hard drive (where folders like /usr, /boot, etc will be stored) and mount /tmp and /home to another hard drive on the same partition?

Something like this:

```
HDD1:

/
  /usr
  /bin
  /boot
  /var


HDD2:

  /tmp
  /home
```

I know LVM is possible for creating a single large volume but that is not what I want

Comment: This is on an existing install. But it was just set up so there isnt a whole lot of stuff to move around

Comment: You should be able to use [these instructions for creating a separate `/home` partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) for both, though for moving `/tmp`, you might not be able to do that without booting from a live CD (or at least using rescue mode). Hopefully someone who has done this can write an answer presenting this information in detail (that documentation is also licensed CC-BY-SA, so with [proper attribution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License), pieces of it can even be included in an answer).

Comment: well. I already have a partition on each drive.  I would like to keep /tmp and /home on the same partition if possible (like how mounting HDD1 as / puts all /usr /var and /boot on the same partition) such that the space is shared

Comment: Ah, I see, you want `/tmp` and `/home` to be on a separate partition from `/` but on the same partition *as each other*. This is slightly less trivial to achieve. I'll post an answer about how to do this (and then someone more experienced moving system directories while they're in use can weigh in as well).

Comment: right now I have HDD1 partitioned as /dev/sda5 (swap), /dev/sda6 (/), /dev/sda7 (/vm -- to store virtual machines); HDD2 is currently formatted as /dev/sdb5 (swap, /dev/sdb6 (/tmp); I'd like to have /dev/sdb6 store both /tmp and /home

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have `/tmp` and `/home` on the same partition as each other but a different partition from `/`, you'll need to do this:

1. Make `tmp` and `home` the two top-level directories on the partition you want to contain them. So if right now that partition is itself `/tmp`, you'll need to move its entire contents to a `tmp` directory in its root.
2. Give the partition that contains `tmp` and `home` its own mount point. A reasonable name for this is `tmp+home` (unless you plan to use that partition for other stuff too) and reasonable locations for it are `/`, `/mnt`, and `/media`. I recommend putting it directly in `/` and the rest of this answer assumes that's where it is.
3. Give `/tmp+home` its own entry in `/etc/fstab`. *(You will see `/tmp` has its own entry.)*
4. Make `/tmp` and `/home` symbolic links to `/tmp+home/tmp` and `/tmp+home/home`.

Please note that this will **not** involve using [these instructions for creating a separate `/home` partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving), because in this configuration, `/home` will be a *symbolic link into* a separate partition, rather than a *mount point for* a separate partition.

Furthermore, you'll have to *unconfigure* your separate `/tmp` directory (including removing or, better, commenting out its entry in `/etc/fstab`), since `/tmp` will no longer be a mount point for a separate partition, but will instead be a symbolic link into a separate partition.

This answer doesn't provide extremely specific instructions (though it should be sufficient, combined with the available documentation). *If someone who has experience moving `/tmp` can weigh in on whether or not it's possible/safe to move `/tmp` while in the installed system, that would be helpful. I can give detailed instructions for doing this from the installed system or from a live CD, but I don't want to give directions that are ineffective or unsafe (nor directions that are unnecessarily difficult and time-consuming).*

Comment: I can't think of any risks with moving `/tmp` besides the idea that if you unmount it and a process wants to access it then it might (extremely worst case scenario) cause a kernel panic. If `fstab` hadn't been changed then you could restart and try again later. If it had, and the mount point was invalid or non existent yet, the OS could fail to boot, or it could chug on without it. In any case, *better safe than sorry*. Likely as not though there wouldn't be a panic in the first place, the process would just end or carry on regardless.

Comment: @jackweirdy An app finding it can't access data won't cause a *kernel panic*, but I'm worried that if important apps or services need `/tmp` and it's moved under them, the system might not remain functional while the other steps are followed. Furthermore, in general *any file or directory in `/tmp` is considered eligible for deletion anytime when it's not actively in use by some process*, so if the contents of `/home` go into a partition that's still mounted as `/tmp`... You can definitely use a live CD, but I'm hoping someone whose done it in a running system can comment (or edit my answer).

Comment: Just tried following your instructions (only to a new partition though). Went fine :)

Comment: Upvote and marked as answer since it works and there doesnt seem to be a better way to do it without an extra mount point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to make another **`/`** partition with an install disk then reboot, and mount that partition temporarily in **`/media`** or whatever then copy the **`/home`** and **`/tmp`** folders in the new **`/`** root partition you mounted under media. Unmount it and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

**Note - Follow instructions at your own peril! I'm confident they will work, but I don't want to be responsible for losing all your stuff**

As someone who has `/home` on a dedicated partition (but not hard drive) I can say its possible, although it's much easier to do with the ubuntu installer when you first install ubuntu.

However, if you need to do this without reinstalling ubuntu I would say it's best to put a small linux OS or livecd (I recommend [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux.com) due to its small size) onto a USB stick or CD and use that to adjust your Hard Disk setup and `/etc/fstab` file, which contains the list of which partitions and Hard Drives hold which folders. I'll continue assuming you use puppy linux to do this, but the steps are easy to follow if you use - for example - an ubuntu livecd.

Once puppy linux is installed (use unetbootin to do this if you are using a USB stick) first need to use Gparted (the graphical partition editor included with puppy linux) to ensure the new hard drive is formatted correctly. It isn't crucial, but it is helpful to use the same filesystem across the two hard drives. I would also suggest you create a partition for `/tmp` and a partition for `/home`. The reasoning for this will become clear.

Once you have these partitions created you need to mount the HDD containing the Ubuntu installation, and copy the contents of the `home` folder to the partition you have created for it. There shouldn't be anything in `/tmp`.

Next, open the file `etc/fstab` for text editing.

**Note - ensure you open the file *within the ubuntu drive*, otherwise you'll be editing the mount details for the livecd/puppy linux**

The layout of the `fstab` file is like this:

`UUID=unique-partition-id[TAB-HERE]/home[TAB-HERE]ext4[TAB-HERE]defaults[TAB-HERE]0[TAB-HERE]2`

(The tabs weren't rendered so I put where they go in square brackets. They aren't strictly necessary but they make the file a hell of a lot easier to read)

append this line **twice**, once for the `home` directory, and once for `tmp`. Ensure that the `ext4` line is changed to match the filesystem used by the partition, and that the `unique-partition-id` field is changed to match the UUID of the partition. that value  can be found in gparted (or the ubuntu disk management utility on a livecd).

Delete the contents of the original home directory - **ensuring all files copied across** - then save the changes to `etc/fstab` and restart.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about how to put `/tmp` and `/home` on a different partition from `/` but *the same partition as each other*. This **can** be done.

Comment: I noticed that, but that would include mounting `/` twice in the fstab. This specific requirement has caused me problems before (admittedly in the 2.20s of the kernel) but I wouldn't want to risk it again.

Comment: You don't have to (and indeed you're right, you **should never**) have two `fstab` entries for `/`. You should never try to use one directory as a mount point for more than one partition. Instead,  just make `/tmp` and `/home` directories in the root of their partition, mount the root of their partition on its own mount point, and make `/tmp` and `/home` symbolic links to the respective subdirectories of that mount point. See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/149091/22949) for details.